# Can you make the "graphic" option of LTXinputExample able to render all pages of a multi-page PDF file?

Tags: showexpl

I have a source code named `source.tex` which produces a PDF file consisting of more than one page. The source code will be displayed by `LTXinputExample` as a formatted text and the corresponding output is provided by the existing PDF file via `graphic` option.

The problem is that `graphic` only shows the first page, the remaining pages are ignored. 
I want all pages to be shown in matrix form.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{source.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\newpage
\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex source}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset
{
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
\LTXinputExample[graphic=source,pos=b,width=4cm,justification=\centering]{source.tex}
\end{document}
```

Can you make the `graphic` option of `LTXinputExample` able to render all pages of a multi-page PDF file?

### Edit:

Could you merge the Doctor Herbert's solution with the following to get the better layout?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcount\x
\newcommand\IncludeOutput[1]{% #1: filename without extension 
    \lstinputlisting[frame=single]{"#1.tex"}
  \pdfximage{"#1.pdf"}%
    \loop
        \ifnum\x<\pdflastximagepages
            \advance\x by 1
            \noindent\hfill
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\fboxrule-1cm,page=\x]{"#1"}}%                      
        \ifnum\x<\pdflastximagepages
            \advance\x by 1
            \hfill
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\fboxrule-1cm,page=\x]{"#1"}}%
        \fi
        \hfill\null\par
    \repeat
}

\begin{document}
    \IncludeOutput{DummyText}
    And more text follows\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, not by default. You would have to patch `\SX@resultInput` and insert a loop.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It is beyond my ability. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put the following into a file `showexpl.cfg` and save it in a directory where TeX will find it with `kpsewhich` (running `texhash` maybe needed). At least put it into the document directory. The file is automatically read by showexpl and redefines the output routine.

```
\RequirePackage{multido}
\newsavebox\SX@tempbox
\renewcommand*\SX@resultInput{%
  \ifx\SX@graphicname\@empty
    \begingroup
      \MakePercentComment\makeatother\catcode`\^^M=5\relax
      \SX@@preset\SX@preset
      \if@SX@rangeaccept
       \let\SX@tempa=\SX@input
      \else
       \let\SX@tempa=\input
      \fi
      \SX@tempa{\SX@codefile}\par%
    \endgroup
  \else
  \sbox\SX@tempbox{\includegraphics{\SX@graphicname}}
    \multido{\iP=1+1}{\pdflastximagepages}{%
      \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\SX@graphicparam,page=\iP]{\SX@graphicname}}
  \fi
}
%% End of file `showexpl.cfg'.
```

If you want to frame also the result then it needs a lot of other code changes. However, it doesn't really make sense ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{source.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\newpage
\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex source}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{frame=single,rframe=}

\begin{document}
\LTXinputExample[graphic=source,pos=b,width=4cm,justification=\raggedright]{source.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]