# How to use pgfpages for creating sheets of labels

Tags: pgfpages

I am trying to create sheets of labels using `pgfpages` but, apparently, I'm doing it wrong. Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2in,paperheight=2in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

% Layout from http://www.onlinelabels.com/OL3016.htm
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{OL3016}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight}%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}%
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}%
  \edef\labelheight{2in}%
  \edef\labelwidth{2in}%
  \edef\labelmargin{0.25in}%
  \edef\labelxsep{1in}%
  \edef\labelysep{0.8333in}%
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=12,%
    last logical shipout=12,
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=1,%
  }
%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {% 
    %copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{1.25in}{1.25in}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{4.25in}{1.25in}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{7.25in}{1.25in}%
  }%
%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {% 
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{1.25in}{3.25in+\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{1.25in+3in}{3.25in+\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{7.25in}{3.25in+\labelysep}%
  }%  
%  
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{7}
  {% 
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{1.25in}{5.25in+2*\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{8}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{4.25in}{5.25in+2*\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{9}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{7.25in}{5.25in+2*\labelysep}%
  }%  
%  
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{10}
  {% 
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{1.25in}{7.25in+3*\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{11}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{4.25in}{7.25in+3*\labelysep}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{12}
  {%
    copy from=1,%
    border code=\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\labelwidth,%
    resized height=\labelheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{7.25in}{7.25in+3*\labelysep}%
  }%  
}


\pgfpagesuselayout{OL3016}[letterpaper]

\begin{document}

This is my label 1.\clearpage
This is my label 2.\clearpage
This is my label 3.\clearpage
This is my label 4.\clearpage
This is my label 5.\clearpage
This is my label 6.\clearpage
This is my label 7.\clearpage
This is my label 8.\clearpage
This is my label 9.\clearpage
This is my label 10.\clearpage
This is my label 11.\clearpage
This is my label 12.\clearpage
This is my label 13.\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I was expection to have one sheet with 12 copies of the same label (because of the `copy from` option). What I am getting is the first physical page with label 1 -- 12 and the next with label 13 and eleven label 1.

Can `pgfpages` be used to declare a layout with 12 copies of the same logical page on each physical page?

Comment: Sorry, not an answer, but that looks like an extremely complicated solution to a relatively simple problem. Is there any reason you can't use the `labels` package?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: You are right. Putting labels on a grid is not a difficult problem and can be done in many ways. I am currently doing something very similar to what Ignasi suggests in his answer (i.e. a two-document process). However, a `pgfpages` solution would allow me to make a small package declaring the layouts for each of the label sheets that I am using. Stating `\pgfpagesuselayout{OL3016}` in the preamble of any document would then rearrange it for printing on OL3016 labels. No special markup would be needed in the document.

Comment: I've updated my answer. May be still not what you want, but I hope it could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but another solution to your problem. What I propose is to draw all your labels in a file and make copies with [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/mirror/pdfpages) package help.

Your labels file will be:

```
%----labels.tex ---------%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2in,paperheight=2in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is my label 1.\clearpage
This is my label 2.\clearpage
This is my label 3.\clearpage
This is my label 4.\clearpage
This is my label 5.\clearpage
This is my label 6.\clearpage
This is my label 7.\clearpage
This is my label 8.\clearpage
This is my label 9.\clearpage
This is my label 10.\clearpage
This is my label 11.\clearpage
This is my label 12.\clearpage
This is my label 13.\clearpage
\end{document}
```

After creating your `labels.pdf`, create a `printlabels.tex` with:

```
%----printlabels.tex----------
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-13},% which labels do you want to print
    delta=.5in 0.8333in,% space between copies
    frame,% comment if don't want frames
   noautoscale,% keep original labels size
   nup=3x4,% how many labels on physical page
   duplicatepages=12 % how many copies of same label
]{labels.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` it and you will get what you want: a 13 pages pdf file with 12 copies of one label in each page.

**Update:**

Applying [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80557/1952) to [Can you make the "graphic" option of LTXinputExample able to render all pages of a multi-page PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80276/can-you-make-the-graphic-option-of-ltxinputexample-able-to-render-all-pages-of/80557#80557), it's possible to reduce my previous answer to one file processed once.

With [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/packages/filecontents) package, `labels.tex` file is included in `printlabels.tex` and processed with `\immediate\write18{pdflatex lables.tex}` command. After that labels are replicated with `pdfpages` command.

You only need to change `geometry` options to fix labels size.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mylabels.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2in,paperheight=2in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is my label 1.\clearpage
This is my label 2.\clearpage
This is my label 3.\clearpage
This is my label 4.\clearpage
This is my label 5.\clearpage
This is my label 6.\clearpage
This is my label 7.\clearpage
This is my label 8.\clearpage
This is my label 9.\clearpage
This is my label 10.\clearpage
This is my label 11.\clearpage
This is my label 12.\clearpage
This is my label 13.\clearpage
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex mylabels.tex}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-13},%
    delta=.5in 0.8333in,%
    frame,%
   noautoscale,%
   nup=3x4,%
    duplicatepages=12]{mylabels.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggested approach to the problem and the solution which I will adapt to suit my needs. Including the labels in a `filecontents` environment is a nice trick.

Comment: @MartinHeller Glad to help you!